# how to add resource as file path

Tags: android

I am using below code for resolving memory issue.My images are present in res/drawable named as 123.jpg.I am following below tutorial

http://android-solution-sample.blogspot.com/2011/10/bitmap-out-of-memory.html

```
 BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();

 o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
 BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, o);
 fis.close();
 final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
 int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
 int scale = 1;
 while (true) {
     if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
         break;
     width_tmp /= 2;
     height_tmp /= 2;
     scale *= 2;
 }
 BitmapFactory.Options op = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 op.inSampleSize = scale;
 fis = new FileInputStream(files[i].getAbsolutePath());
 bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis, null, op);
 fis.close();
```

Comment: FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(how to give resouce path here);

Comment: my file is in drwable folder in resource how i write inputstream file path

Comment: Why do you keep this file in res/drawable? Maybe you can move it to asset folder?

Comment: Here is method for res: context.getResources().openRawResource(ID_OF_RESOURCE). 
Your image has very strange name (first char is numeral - it is incorrect) rename it.